# MySQL restart on the server the memory used by mySQL has increased from 1.8 GB to 9.2 GB This resulted in 97% of the Server memory being in used

Tags: mysql, database-administration

MySQL restart on the server the memory used by mySQL has increased from 1.8 GB to 9.2 GB This resulted in 97% of the Server memory being in used

Any tuning need to be set on my.cnf file.

Every week I am manually restarting server

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault **@Anand**! Have you tried any config change? Share with us any action you did to solve it. Give us more information in order to help you, e.g. some relevant part of logs, config files, computer status or the information source you are using to configure.

Comment: Are you talking about RAM?  Or disk space?

Comment: This probably belongs in dba.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

If surge in data is due to your application's data being inserted, then I would suggest to move MySQL database to some other drive which has huge space.

If this isn't your application data, dig through to see what data is getting generated and stop insertion if that's not required.

MySQL system tables won't generate this huge amount of data.